# Can not init ORDImage Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to init ORDImage. 
I have tried diffrent parameters (specifing file) and empty init, like on screenshot.

[image: ordimage init]

Here is my table definition

```
CREATE TABLE Meals
(
    id       INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    category INTEGER                                                            NOT NULL,
    name     VARCHAR(100 CHAR)                                                  NOT NULL,
    price    DOUBLE PRECISION                                                   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT category_constraint FOREIGN KEY (category) REFERENCES Categories (id),
    image    ORDIMAGE
);
```

So where is my mistake? This example is very similar to docs:

```
BEGIN INSERT INTO pm.online_media (product_id, product_photo)  VALUES (3501, ORDSYS.ORDImage.init()); COMMIT;END;/
```

I am using Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OrdImage is part of Oracle Multimedia  [which was deprecated in 18c and removed in 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/upgrd/behavior-changes-deprecated-desupport-oracle-database.html#GUID-BABC1C60-EA07-4EBE-8C67-B69B59E4F742)